# How to create pie chart using html and css and send to in email in Django templates?

Tags: python, html, css, django-templates

I want to create pie chart using highcharts.js and attach to email but when i send email charts not render, can anybody help me to render chart in email attachements.

Answer (score 0):

Django's 1.7 in [send_email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) method the `html_message` parameter was added.

Go with this:-

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


msg_plain = render_to_string('templates/email.txt', {'some_params': some_params})
msg_html = render_to_string('templates/email.html', {'some_params': some_params})

send_mail(
    'email title',
    msg_plain,
    'some@sender.com',
    ['some@receiver.com'],
    html_message=msg_html,
)
```